# How do I remove HTTP authentication on a website on a FreeBSD Server?

Tags: freebsd, http-authentication

Sorry that I haven't done much of my own research but I do not know how to set up basic authentication, nevermind removing it!

Thanks.

EDIT:
Sorry, what was I thinking, its in httpd.conf or includes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), but I'm going to carry on and assume you're using Apache on FreeBSD.

The authentication is set in either the `httpd.conf` (main Apache configuration file) or a `.htaccess` file in the directory that serves the protected content.

In the `httpd.conf` file, you'll come across a `Directory` or `Location` statement which matches, respectively, either the physical filesystem directory where the protected content is stored, or the URI of the protected content.

In either case, the authentication is a set of lines beginning with Auth.  Simply comment those out - if they're in the httpd.conf file, you'll need to restart your Apache server, if in a .htaccess file it should take effect right away.

**Examples:**

In `httpd.conf`, files in `/srv/www/protected` are protected by authentication:

```
<Directory /srv/www/protected>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "My Protected Site"
    ...
</Directory>
```

Or, within the `/srv/www/protected` directory in a file called `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "My Protected Site"
...
```